# How to activate HDMI as my default output starting from BIOS, GRUB, GDM,  and Desktop?

Tags: 11.04, xorg, hdmi, hd-video

Ubuntu 11.04, when i boot, i do not see anything in my HD TV screen. No Bios/Grub/Gdm/Desktop. How can i use my default HDMI output please?

Note: I have VGA port, but i do not use any VGA Screen/Monitor. Only for special repairing purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this is selectable in the BIOS of the machine. I have a system with an NVidia card that has both HDMI and VGA outputs. In the BIOS, I had to select "Primary Display Port" as "HDMI", and then it would always default to HDMI for BIOS, grub, console, etc output.

Comment: I have a mother board which does not have BIOS such option. It has only HDMI, DVI output. So i am using DVI to VGA adapter. But anyway if we can do it with Ubuntu OS settings, would be nice answer. (My bios does not have what you mentioned, but in other machines i have seen)