# Dual-Boot : Command to force boot Windows after a reboot

Tags: dual-boot

I have a computer using a Dual-Boot with Ubuntu and Windows. While connected on Ubuntu, I would like to use a command to reboot the computer and start Windows.

After Windows turns off, the computer would ideally start Ubuntu again.

Is anything like this possible ?

Comment: The short answer is no, it isn't.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I'll experiment with GRUB and create my own method then. If I can modify boot orders from Ubuntu and Windows when they boot, maybe it could work.

Comment: At best you can change Grub to boot Windows by default. You can't do the reverse from Windows obviously. And then if you want to boot Ubuntu you'll have to manually select it instead, this until you change Grub's default again.

Comment: Grub has reboot command. https://askubuntu.com/questions/859335/grub-menu-gets-skipped-when-using-hdmi-cable/859530#859530 & more details but was reboot into Windows 7. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2309436&p=13423016#post13423016

Comment: @oldfred grub-reboot is exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you !

Comment: @user68186 Thank you, grub-reboot was the commadn I was looking for. Thank you !